# how jmx could help in development of highly scalable distributed applications?

Tags: java, jmx

I am new to JMX, and wanted to know what are some best practices and patterns of using JMX in distributed applications?

Answer (score 2):

Start here:   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/best-practices-jsp-136021.html

On a personal experience note:

- Do instrument with jmx
- Be as consistent as possible in your usages
- Don't neglect comments and meaningful names (this forms a user interface)
- For any methods which take user input, clean it first (not just the obvious protection against harmful characters, but also trim whitespace and normalize cases)

Answer (score 2):

We used JMX as an RPC layer for one of our apps. We used it because it's a bit higher level than raw RMI, and eliminated much of the cruft of RMI. On top of that, we got to leverage the ubiquity of JMX (such as JConsole, 3rd party tools, etc.) which we would not have had for RMI.

As to performance, scaling, etc., we didn't look in to that as it wasn't an important aspect of our project.

But it was certainly easier to use than RMI, and performed well for us.